# Hide parent IF child span is set to display:none

Tags: jquery, hide

I have gone through most similar JQuery posts relating to hiding parent containers but none of the options seemed to work for me.

In a nutshell I have the following code

```
<div id="pagination" class="pagination">
  <span class="previous disabled">« Previous</span>
  <span class="next disabled">Next »</span>
</div>
```

*Not my coding btw :-p

Currently the pagination div (above) on my store is empty - this happens because the pagination has not been triggered to show the previous and next spans in the above code. You can see that they have a class name of .disabled which just sets those spans to display:none.

I would like to create a Jquery function that hides the parent div #pagination when the child span.previous and span.next are set to .disabled.

Thanks for your help in advanced!

Comment: Cannot be done in pure CSS. Unless the parent itself has some identifier (class or id)

Comment: Apologises PeeHaa - this was a JQuery related question, I tagged it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
$('.pagination').each(function(){
   var $this = $(this);
    if($('span.next', this).hasClass('disabled') && $('span.previous', this).hasClass('disabled')){
       $this.hide();
    }
});
```

fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/hwrx2/

Comment: This is very close to what I had, except for the && for the second span tag. Thanks mate... much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is untested:

```
$(".pagination:has(.previous.disabled):has(.next.disabled)").hide();
```

or

```
$(".pagination").has(".previous.disabled").has(".next.disabled").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

My first approach if I wouldn't write "logic" code would be to change the default: hide the parent and show it only if any of the children are not disabled. With jQuery that's easy:

```
<div id="pagination" class="pagination" style="display:none"> TEST
  <span class="previous disabled">« Previous</span>
  <span class="next disabled">Next »</span>
</div>​

$(':has(:not(span.disabled))').css('display', 'block');​
```